# How to query multi 'or' and a and in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

a table like this

table

```
|primary_key|  project | tag |
|    1      |    2     |  3  |
|    2      |    2     |  0  |
|    3      |    2     |  4  |
|    4      |    2     |  5  |
|    5      |    3     |  0  |
|    6      |    2     |  0  |
```

I want to query project with tag ' (3 and 4) or (0 and 4) and (5 and 0)',
In this example, the output should be project 2?
how could I write this in a SQL?
I tried using phpmyadmin to generate several result, but not work as I expect.

It's realy kind of your  guys to help me.
I change the question, if the condition is much more complex, can the query be 
from 
table a, table b, table c?

Comment: can you please clarify `(3|0) and 4` how can it be either 3 or 0 and equal to 4 all at the same time???

Comment: sorry, should be (3 and 4 ) | (0 and 4)

Comment: yeah... that would be the same as `(3|0) and 4` just written differently. If you are wanting to group your the rows by project first then use Gordon's answer below. I did not understand at first that you wanted to group rows. now its all clear.

Comment: fiddle from answer @Gordon Linoff http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7d67/1/0

Comment: now the last edit does make it different than the original...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the table to itself and check if every row with tag 3/0 has another row with tag 4.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.project
FROM table a, table b
WHERE a.project= b.project AND
    ( a.tag = 3 AND b.tag = 4 ) OR 
    ( a.tag = 0 AND b.tag = 4 )
```

Updated according to the updated question.

Comment: that query is going to return 0 rows no matter what data you have in the table.

Comment: No. Think about it - tag can't be 3 and 4, it's one of the other!

Comment: returns project 2 in multiple rows, DISTINCT

Comment: still one question, if the query is much more complex, could the query be "from table a, table b, table c"?

Comment: @cui wouldn't that be something you should be in the original question if the table is a temp table made from an already formed query?

Comment: @cui you can keep extending the `WHERE` as long as you have `OR something else`. If you want to have `AND something else` you will have to join in with the same table again like `table c`

Answer (score 4):

You want to do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select project
from t
group by project
having sum(tag = 0 or tag = 3) > 0 and
       sum(tag = 4) > 0;
```

Each `sum()` expression is counting the number of rows where the condition is true.  So, the two conditions are saying "there is at least one row with tag = 0 or 3 and there is at least one row with tag = 4".

Comment: is it faster to do it via aggregation and not using `EXISTS`, because I figure the sum has to be calculated, i.e. evaluate each row...just curious

Comment: @DrCopyPaste . . . It depends on the indexes and the database engine (MySQL is particularly bad for aggregations).  However, remember that `distinct` is often doing very similar processing to `group by`, so even `join`-based solutions may have similar performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct
    a.project
from
    `table` a
        join
    `table` b ON b.project = a.project and b.tag = 4
where
    a.tag in (0 , 3)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=2/9c3a1/6/0#!2/f861f5/2)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the query for the most recent edit `(3 and 4) or (0 and 4) and (5 and 0)` Not sure whether though it is `((3 and 4) or (0 and 4)) and (5 and 0)` OR `(3 and 4) or ((0 and 4) and (5 and 0))` So i chose the former.

```
SELECT
    project
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    project
HAVING
    (sum(tag = 3 AND tag = 4) > 0 OR
    sum(tag = 0 AND tag = 4) > 0) AND
    sum(tag = 5 AND tag = 0)
```